# Returning OS and browser with flash version of uploadify using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Tags: mysql, flash, browser, operating-system, uploadify

I am using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to return the user's OS and browser when uploads are successfully completed using uploadifive. I have to use a flash fallback for browsers that don't yet support HTML5, i.e. the script falls back to uploadify. After successful uploads I have a script which submits data to a MySQL database, including the OS and browser.  This works fine with uploadifive, but for uploadify 'Adobe Flash Player 11' is returned. I am wondering if there is a workaround to return the OS and browser when using flash?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. If the user is interested in *not* providing this information to you, you will not get it. But if they don't care / would like to provide it, then you can do it through http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/#!flash/system/Capabilities.html `os` property. You can also query JavaScript through ExternalInterface for navigator.

However, in general, Flash may send requests all by itself, i.e. being the user agent, not needing other user agents.

These headers are generated by the client-side software, which inherently cannot be trusted. Nothing can prevent the user from sending whatever information with the request. So, by handling the particular case of Flash not sending something you expect you aren't fixing the problem, you should be ready to have just any random information in that field, or, maybe, none at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have now found another answer on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/751380/672147).  It looks like I can just add the code in this answer to the actionscript in my flash file.  How then would I get this info, i.e. var t to be submitted to my MSQL table, i.e. t.text or var v?